# Is it possible to document a function in JSDoc that's not defined locally?

Tags: node.js, jsdoc

The basic pattern that I have a couple of times in my code is `exports.thing = thingFromSomewhereElse`, and I want to document the function members of `thingFromSomewhereElse` as though I had defined them myself. But I can't see how do do that without an actual `thing.functionName = function() {...}`. If I try to use the `@callback` tag, JSDoc classifies it as a type definition instead of a member. Is there a way to get it to properly display as an object member?

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by using the `@name` JSDoc tag. That tag is intended to be used to write a comment for something that would not be recognized by JSDoc. The `@kind` tag should also be used to indicate that the thing being documented is actually a function, so that the function-specific tags like `@param` and `@return` work properly. For the example given, the function would be documented with a comment like this:

```
/**
 * Description of the function
 * @name thing.functionName
 * @kind function
 * @param ...
 * @return ...
 */
```